# Approval process- Configuring approvers

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I have a opportunity which has lookup to account. In opportunity approval process- approval step- i need to have a approver as Account's manager--> Manager.

In another step, Approver as Account's manager--> Manager --> Manager.

I am struck here, can anyone suggest any approach here in config level.

Comment: You need to create a Lookup field 'Account Manager' on Opportunity and auto-populate it on Before Insert Trigger of Opportunity and After Update Trigger of Account. Create another field called as Manager and populate the same on Trigger as mentioned above.
Use the field in approval process accordingly.

Comment: @DhananjayPatil: We have only user field at the approver level.

Comment: then what is 
"In another step, Approver as Account's manager--> Manager --> Manager."
about? Sounds like u wanted to 2nd approver as Account Manager's Manager?

Comment: Yes @DhananjayPatil

Comment: so you need to setup 2 step approval process here.for this 2 new fields. Account Manager and their manager needs to be created on Opportunity as mentioned in earlier comments.